# Twitter won't link to Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

I had previously linked my personal Twitter and Facebook accounts, then unlinked them.

Now I am trying to link them again, and no matter what I do, I get the following message:

> "You're currently logged in to Facebook with a different account than the one you have linked to."

I have deleted the app within Facebook itself.  At this point, I try to link the accounts again from `Settings->Apps->Facebook Connect`.  It then says "Continue as [my name]?"  So clearly it detects that I'm logged in under my name.  And yet at the end, I get this same error message.

Clearly, I am not logged in to Facebook with a different account.  What happened?!

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser? Have you tried logging completely out of Facebook?

Comment: Yes, I have tried several different browsers, logging out, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just logged out of both Twitter & FB on Chrome, opened Internet Explorer/Edge/whatever, logged into Twitter & voila! That finally worked.  I was able to link my Twitter account to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the cause of this problem. What you can do is logout from Facebook and twitter from all devices. Now login Facebook from laptop or desktop instead of Facebook app and try to link your Twitter account.

Here is the direct link:
https://www.facebook.com/twitter/

Clear your browser cache before login Facebook.